# Cauchy-hadamard formula

Tags: real-analysis

Can we get the radius of convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}b_nx^n $ is not less than the radius of convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^n $? where,
$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}b_nx^n\leq \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^n$, for all $x>0$ and $a_n\,,b_n$ are positive

Comment: Suppose $S$ is a series with radius of convergence $R$. What is the radius of convergence of $cS$ where $c \neq 0$? Use this.

Comment: could you give me some more details?

Answer (score 1):

Let $R_a$ and $R_b$ be, respectively, the radii of convergence of the power series $a(x)=\sum a_nx^n$ and $b(x)=\sum b_nx^n$, and suppose $R_b<\infty$ (otherwise is trivial). Then for all $\epsilon>0$ we have $b(R_b+\epsilon)=\infty$, so $a(R_b+\epsilon)=\infty$. Thus, $R_b+\epsilon$ is outside the radius of convergence of $a(x)$, that is $R_b+\epsilon\geq R_a$. From this we conclude that $R_b\geq R_a$.